# Inconsistent display of UTF-8 across app: garbled in some places, not others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

Using haml, formtastic, rails 3.1.3, ruby 1.9.2, sqlite3 in dev, postgres in production.

I have a form, which successfully encodes strings as utf-8. Strings such as `Słów` are being passed properly in params and written to the database fine in both development and production.

However, after save, the form field displays a garbled `SÅ‚Ã³w`. Placing the attribute on the same page via something like `@work.field` also displays the garblage.

If I call `@work.field` on another template file, it renders fine.

I've done the usual:

```
- Make sure 'config.encoding = "utf-8"' is there in application.rb file.
- Putting '# encoding: utf-8' on top of file containing utf-8 characters.
- Above '<App Name>::Application.initialize!' line in environment.rb file, add following two lines:

Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. I added this in layouts/application.rb which works.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```